# How to perform sum pooling in PyTorch

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, max-pooling, spatial-pooling

How to perform sum pooling in PyTorch. Specifically, if we have input `(N, C, W_in, H_in)` and want output `(N, C, W_out, H_out)` using a particular `kernel_size` and `stride` just like `nn.Maxpool2d` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`torch.nn.AvgPool1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.AvgPool1d) (or [`torch.nn.AvgPool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.AvgPool2d), [`torch.nn.AvgPool3d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.AvgPool3d)) which are performing mean pooling - proportional to sum pooling. If you really want the summed values, you could multiply the averaged output by the pooling surface.

Comment: Do you mean, first I perform Avgpool2d and than multiply the resulting tensor by 4 if my kernel size is 4 ?

Comment: Yes, average pooling first, then multiply back the results by `4 * 4 = 16` if `kernel_size=4` (as it means the average is computed over a region of `4 * 4 = 16` elements).

Answer (score 3):

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AvgPool2d.html#torch.nn.AvgPool2d find divisor_override.
set divisor_override=1
you'll get a sumpool

```
import torch
input = torch.tensor([[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]]])
sumpool = torch.nn.AvgPool2d(2, stride=1, divisor_override=1)
sumpool(input)
```

you'll get

```
tensor([[[ 8,  8],
         [12, 12]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [benjaminplanche's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839590/786020):

I need sum pooling as well and it doesn't seem to directly exist, but it is equivalent to running a conv2d with a weights parameter made of ones. I thought it would be faster to run AvgPool2d and multiply by the kernel size product. Turns out, not exactly.

**Bottom line up front:**

Use [torch.nn.functional.avg_pool2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#avg-pool2d) and its related functions and multiply by the kernel size.

Testing in Jupyter I find:

(Overhead)

```
%%timeit
x = torch.rand([1,1,1000,1000])
>>> 3.49 ms ± 4.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
_=F.avg_pool2d(torch.rand([1,1,1000,1000]), [10,10])*10*10
>>> 4.99 ms ± 74.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

(So 1.50 ms ± 79.0 µs) (I found the `*10*10` only adds around 20 µs to the graph)

`avePool = nn.AvgPool2d([10, 10], 1, 0)`

```
%%timeit
_=avePool(torch.rand([1,1,1000,1000]))*10*10
>>> 80.9 ms ± 1.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

(So 77.4 ms ± 1.58 ms)

`y = torch.ones([1,1,10,10])`

```
%%timeit
_=F.conv2d(torch.rand([1,1,1000,1000]), y)
>>> 14.4 ms ± 421 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

(So 10.9 ms ± 426 µs)

```
sumPool = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 10, 1, 0, 1, 1, False)
sumPool.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(y)
```

```
%%timeit
_=sumPool(torch.rand([1,1,1000,1000]))
>>> 7.24 ms ± 63.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

(So 3.75 ms ± 68.3 µs)

And as a sanity check.

```
abs_err = torch.max(torch.abs(avePool(x)*10*10 - sumPool(x)))
magnitude = torch.max(torch.max(avePool(x)*10*10, torch.max(sumPool(x))))
relative_err = abs_err/magnitude
abs_err.item(), magnitude.item(), relative_err.item()
>>> (3.814697265625e-06, 62.89910125732422, 6.064788493631568e-08)
```

That's probably a reasonable rounding related error.

I do not know why the functional version is faster than making a dedicated kernel, but it looks like if you want to make a dedicated kernel, prefer the Conv2D version, and make the weights untrainable with `sumPool.weights.requires_grad = False` or `with torch.no_grad():` during creation of the kernel parameters. These results may change with kernel size, so test for your own application if you need to speed up this part. Let me know if I missed something...